# Pega 7.3 Connect-Rest with multiple URLS

Tags: docusignapi, pega, connect-rest

I am trying to figure out how to use multiple URLs in a Connect-Rest in Pega 7.3 to connect to DocuSign using the DocuSign Pega integration that is built by Pega.

I have a specific link that contains API keys that I am required to use as the resource path in my Connect-Rest. However, I also have another link that calls a specific instance of DocuSign so that the info from Pega goes directly to the DocuSign instance.

I know that Pega has updated their connect-rest functionality in the current version but my question is does anyone know if there is a way to incorporate multiple urls into one connect-rest.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: From where you are calling this `Connect-Rest` rule ?

Comment: Are you referring to production-level-specific URLs (e.g. a different URL for development than for production)? If yes, system setting rules should work: https://community.pega.com/sites/default/files/help_v73/procomhelpmain.htm#rule-/rule-admin-/rule-admin-system-/rule-admin-system-settings/main.htm?Highlight=Rule-Admin-System-Settings

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you mean by "connect-rest."

DocuSign has the "Connect" feature for sending webhook notifications when an envelope's status changes. All envelope sent by selected (or all) users will be monitored. You can create multiple Connect subscriptions so that multiple URLs will be sent when an envelope's status changes.

DocuSign also has "individual envelope webhooks." This feature is configured when an envelope is created via the API and the create request includes the `EventNotification` attribute. A maximum of one URL can be set per envelope.

Answer (score 0):

If you are invoking Connect-Rest from a pega activity, you can capture the relevant URL as variable and pass that to function call to 'Connect-Rest' within activity. Another useful way maybe to use dynamic system setting and use @(Pega-RULES:Utilities).getSystemSetting() function to read the value of URL saved in the Dynamic system settings